# trying to add events to jQuery event calendar dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, calendar

I'm trying to add events to a jQuery event calendar dynamically:

```
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
          {
          search=new XMLHttpRequest();
          }
        else
          {
          search=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
          }
        search.onreadystatechange=function()
          {
          if (search.readyState==4 && search.status==200)
            {
                nr = search.responseText;
                $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                    events: nr
                });

            }
          }
        search.open("GET","clienti.php",true);
        search.send();
```

and my clienti.php gives me this:

```
[{ title: '0736533586', start: '1388016000'},{ title: '0244453554', start:          '1388102400'},{ title: 'Â Â Â 0244453554', start: '1388275200'}]
```

If I write manually on events parameter in calendar `( events : [ { title: 'something', start: '1388016000' } ] )` it works but when I feed this param with nr variable which contains same information it doesn't work...

Any ideas?

Comment: same result using `eventSources` ? http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/events_array/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your `nr` variable is string the calender api accepts json as parameter to events so try to parse your `nr` variable to json   by `JSON.parse(nr)`

```
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
          {
          search=new XMLHttpRequest();
          }
        else
          {
          search=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
          }
        search.onreadystatechange=function()
          {
          if (search.readyState==4 && search.status==200)
            {
                nr = search.responseText;
                $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                    events: JSON.parse(nr)
                });

            }
          }
        search.open("GET","clienti.php",true);
        search.send();
```